# Which library to import in python to process XLSX, and it is compatible with Apachi POI

Tags: python, apache-poi, xlsx

I am using python 3.4, I need to do some calculation everyday and insert the result into XLSX, and then read the xlsx in apache poi. The problem is I am using openpyxl to insert result into xlsx, but the Apache POI can't open the xlsx processed by openpyxl, so is there any other option which can process xlsx and compatible with Apache POI, or other workaround to make the Apache POI to open the xlsx.

Comment: That's very strange. All these libraries need to be compatible with original XLSX protocol. It must be like if i modify txt file in java, it should be readable in python and notepad++, etc...

Comment: I've googled a bit and at first point it seems that issue with Apache POI and xlxs is common and caused by Java. So probably you shouldn't blame Python :)

Comment: I'm not aware of any bugs reported to Apache POI about openpyxl. Can you be a bit more specific than "Apache POI can't open the xlsx"?

Comment: I use openpyxl to insert values into xlsx everyday, and upload the xlsx to Klipfolio for generating dashboards, Klipfolio uses Apache POI. If I upload the xlsx files directly after it is processed in python, Klipfolio couldn't read anything. So I have to open each xlsx files and click "save" button to re_save the file again and upload the xlsx files, then Klipfolio can read it.

Comment: I have worked together with Kllipfolio regarding this issue, the answer I got from them is: "For the openpyxl Excel data source, the cause of the problem is with something openpyxl is adding or not adding to the document it creates. The Klipfolio parser gets a null pointer in the get sheet comments". So what they suggest me is if openpyxl is not compatibile with Aparche POI, then I have to figure out another solution to insert values into xlsl.

Comment: Sounds to me like it's a bug in Klipfolio not Apache POI. Comments are optional in XLSX files, which POI fully supports, sounds like Klipfolio are blindly carrying on when POI says "Nothing here"....

Answer (score 0):

Try using [XlsxWriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter)

I had a similar problem, so I tried using [XlsxWriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter) instead of openpyxl. This generated a file that was importable into Apache POI.

Example code for XlsxWriter:

```
import xlsxwriter

# Sample data as a list of dictionaries
data = [
    {'Name': 'Alice', 'Age': 30, 'City': 'New York'},
    {'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 28, 'City': 'San Francisco'},
]

# Create a new xlsx file and add a worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Set the format for the first column to be of type text
text_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '@'})

# Write header row with keys from the first dictionary
for col, header in enumerate(data[0].keys()):
    worksheet.write(0, col, header)

# Write data rows
for row, record in enumerate(data, start=1):
    for col, (key, value) in enumerate(record.items()):
        worksheet.write(row, col, value)

# Close the workbook and save the xlsx file
workbook.close()
```

Note:
I asume we have the same problem because when I uploaded a file generated by openpyxl to an apache website it gave me an error message: **The numbers of columns was incorrect.** After manualy opening the excel it showed the correct number of columns. When saving excel file in the excel application i was able to upload it to the website.